# Quotient of infinitesimals

Tags: limits

I have a question regarding division by infinity. I have the following problem:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and I would think that I can make a substituion $t = \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$. As $n\to \infty$ the value of $t$ gets smaller and smaller until it gets infinitesimally small which is I belive what the $0^+$ in the one sided limit stands for. I know that in this case it would not make much difference but is it possible to write the limit as $\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{1}{t} \log\left(1-t\right) = \frac{1}{0^+} \log\left(1^-\right)=\frac{0^-}{0^+}=-1$ instead of writing is as $\lim_{t \to 0}$ and using the l'Hospital's rule and eventually getting to the same result?

Comment: I'm confused why you say that $\frac{0^-}{0^+}=-1$.

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: @Vojtech: It sounds like you're trying to use the ideas of non-standard analysis, but notions like $0^-$ are a different approach to things, and can't be treated as if they were hyperreal numbers.

Comment: @Hurkyl: That is exactly what got me confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it, but that doesn't make it a valid derivation. Both $\frac{0}{0}$ and $\frac{1}{0} \log 1$ are indeterminate forms; this method of using things like $0^+$ to keep track of additional information allows you to correctly restrict the overall sign to be nonpositive, but it's still not enough to tell which numbers in $[-\infty, 0]$ are limit points.

All of the same explanations as to why $\frac{0}{0}$ is an indeterminate form still apply to $\frac{0^-}{0^+}$.

Answer (score 1):

Considering [The Infinitesimal Functions](http://portal.tpu.ru/SHARED/k/KONVAL/Sites/English_sites/calculus/2_InfinitesimalClass_f.htm) your solution is correct. In fact, when $\alpha(x)\sim0$ while $x\to 0$ then $\ln(1+\alpha(x))\sim\alpha(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer your question with a question: What does your method yield for the following limit?
 $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \log\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)$$
And what does l'Hôpital say about the same limit?